# How suppress `unused-property` error in vulture

Tags: python

I have noticed that [vulture](https://github.com/jendrikseipp/vulture) package started to report new error `vulture: unused-property`.
The [documentation](https://github.com/jendrikseipp/vulture/blob/main/README.md) specifies following errors code (just like for flake8 - https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/error-codes.html):

- F401 - `unused-import`
- F841 - `unused-variable`

There is no code specified for `unused-property` though. I would like to have a code so I can suppress just this error (instead of using `# noqa` to suppress all errors in the line) as I use other linters as well.

Comment: SO is not a tech support group. This sounds like something you should ask the Vulture developer on their github site.